# How to add EventHandler for all cells in a TableView without creating a new CellFactory for each column?

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to allow the user to middle-click on any cell in a `TableView` and copy its text to the system clipboard. However, I can't figure out how to loop through all the **cells** in a `TableView`.

Is there a way to get a `List` of all `TableCells` in a row or column so I can apply the `setOnMouseClicked()` method to them?

I understand this can be done easily with a `CellFactory`; but I already have a few custom factories applied to some of the columns, and I need to avoid overriding those or creating 20+ cell factories for the rest of the columns.

Here is a MCVE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class TableCellClickListener extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple Interface
        VBox root = new VBox(10);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        TableView<Person> tableView = new TableView<>();

        TableColumn<Person, String> colName = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        colName.setCellValueFactory(tf -> tf.getValue().nameProperty());

        TableColumn<Person, Number> colBalance = new TableColumn<>("Balance");
        colBalance.setCellValueFactory(tf -> tf.getValue().balanceProperty());

        tableView.getColumns().addAll(colName, colBalance);

        // Format the balance column
        colBalance.setCellFactory(t -> new TableCell<Person, Number>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Number item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    setText(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(item));
                }
            }
        });

        // This is where I am stuck; is there such a list of cells in the API?
        for (TableCell cell : listOfCells) {
            setCopyListener(cell);
        }

        // Show the stage
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Sample");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void setCopyListener(TableCell cell) {
        cell.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            if (!cell.isEmpty() && event.getButton().equals(MouseButton.MIDDLE)) {
                System.out.println(cell.getText());
            }
        });
    }
}

class Person {

    private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final DoubleProperty balance = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

    public Person(String name, double balance) {
        this.name.set(name);
        this.balance.set(balance);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return balance.get();
    }

    public void setBalance(double balance) {
        this.balance.set(balance);
    }

    public DoubleProperty balanceProperty() {
        return balance;
    }
}
```

---

I have the `setCopyListener(TableCell cell)` method ready to go, but I cannot find a way to loop through all the cells without a `CellFactory` for each column. I've looked through the Java documentation and cannot find a way to access a list of all the cells in a row or column.

Am I missing it?

Comment: don't see the problem: call setCopyListener in your factory (vs. trying not-existing and unwanted api to grab them some time after having created a cell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cells are created by the skin and they won't be available before the first layout pass. Furthermore resizing the `TableView` may result in additional cells being created. Either you create a custom skin for the `TableView` or you use the fact that `MouseEvent` provides a `pickResult` property that contains the node under the mouse to your advantage.

Note: The node contained in the `pickResult` could be a descendant of a `TableCell` or not part of a cell at all (e.g. the column header or scrollbar). You need to iterate up though the node hierarchy until you either find a cell or the `TableView`.

```
tableView.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, evt -> {
    if (evt.getButton() == MouseButton.MIDDLE) {
        TableCell<Person, ?> cell = findCell(evt, tableView);
        if (cell != null && !cell.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(cell.getText());
            evt.comsume();
        }
    }
});
```

```
private static <T> TableCell<T, ?> findCell(MouseEvent event, TableView<T> table) {
    Node node = event.getPickResult().getIntersectedNode();

    // go up in node hierarchy until a cell is found or we can be sure no cell was clicked
    while (node != table && !(node instanceof TableCell)) {
        node = node.getParent();
    }
    return node instanceof TableCell ? (TableCell<T, ?>) node : null;
}
```

Comment: while possible, this is a questionable approach .. a) don't do stuff on behalf of any control, let the control itself handle it b) for a cell that means to configure its behavior at instantiation time